# MVC Sidebar don't stay active after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC.net, having difficulty to get through bootstrap sidebar li stay active after click and continue to refresh the page all the time i click.

However i have try to use the example provide below still, it still can't be active after click.

i have try through several answer from the link Click **option1** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11904879/jquery-to-toggle-sub-menu-but-keep-sub-menu-open-if-sub-menu-page-active) 
and Click **option2** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407367/mvc-with-bootstrap-navbar-set-selected-item-to-active)

**Below is my code:**

**CurrentControllerActiveClassName:**

```
 public string CurrentControllerActiveClassName(string targetController)
    {
        var controller = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
        return controller.Equals(targetController) ? "active" : string.Empty;
    }
```

**Html layout:**

```
<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block;">
    <li class="dropdown @CurrentControllerActiveClassName("Option")">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">@Manager.Resource.Value("ABC000") </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Manager.Resource.Value("ABC001"), "Import", "Others Country")</li>  
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Manager.Resource.Value("ABC002"), "Apply", "Accept")</li>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink(Manager.Resource.Value("ABC003"), "Terminate", "Stop Purchasing")</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('li:has(ul)', '#sidebar-content ul').each(function() {    
 if ($(this).hasClass('current') || $(this).hasClass('open-default')) {
     $('>a', this).append("<i class='arrow " + arrow_class_open + "'></i>");
 } else {
     $('>a', this).append("<i class='arrow " + arrow_class_closed + "'></i>");
 }
});

if ($('#sidebar').hasClass('sidebar-fixed')) {
    $('#sidebar-content').append('<div class="fill-nav-space"></div>');
}

$('#sidebar-content ul > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    var navItem = $(this);    //add to try
    if (navItem.find("a").attr("href") == location.pathname) {  //add to try
        navItem.addClass("active");  //add to try
    }
    if ($(this).next().hasClass('sub-menu') == false) {
        return;
    }
```

**The result should be stay active while sidebar is click.**

Comment: We can't see what _@CurrentControllerActiveClassName("Option")_ renders.

Comment: @Mackan i have update it in the question

Comment: ok, it's not easy to follow the jquery when the classes and structure of the html is not shown. My guess is that only the last three lines matter, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Mackan the classes inside the structure is only matter with the content it won't involve with the sidebar

Comment: @Mackan  the varitem inside the jquery is code i try, but adding those into the code also will not work also

Comment: Have you tried with using _e.preventDefault();_, as to stop the "refreshing" and then handling the click-events manually?

Comment: @Mackan yes i have try that, if i add e.preventDefault(); the other page will not be in functioning anymore, looks like if set <li class="active"> will have the same problem too.